# How to parse returned css information using Selenium webdriver.executescript

Tags: javascript, selenium

Newbie to Javascript in Node environment...

Using this code below where the script is getting css values for a particular web element, how do I parse this in javascript?

```
    driver.executeScript(script, ele).then(p => {
       console.log(p);            
    })
```

The code above shows this result in the console.

```
{ class: 'container ng-scope', 'ng-controller': 'CalcCtrl' }
```

It's returned as type Object, so I can't figure out for example how to get the value of the key "class"...

If I change the code to this:

```
driver.executeScript(script, ele).then(p => {
       console.log(p);            
       var obj = JSON.parse(p);
       console.log(obj.class);
    })
```

I get this error...
[image]

Where column 27 is the parse in JSON.parse...

Comment: That's already an object.  You don't need to parse it.

Comment: I want to extract the values of the class key.  Can't that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, is this:

```
    driver.executeScript(script, ele).then(p => {
      if(p.class) console.log(p.class);               
    })
```

JavaScript returns undefined for any key in a JSON object that cannot be found, therefore, the If(p.class) ensures this item of data has a key named class and prints it out.

[image]